# User validation failed pathis required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I am creating a rest api to handle data from in and out the database, so far the database connection is good with the error coming from request.

Here is the code I am working with. The first file is **index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); const mongoose = require('mongoose'); //const dotenv = require('dotenv');

//import routes authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

//dotenv.config()


//connect to db
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Doe:abcdef@cluster0-pqcka.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true }, ()=>console.log('connected to db'))
//connecting to middleware app.use(express.json());
//route middlewares
app.use('/api/user', authRoute);
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('The server is up and running'));
```

I also have another file called **User.js** that stores the value supposed to be in the database i.e name and email. Here is the document

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
**name**:{ 
 type:String,
 required:true,
 min:6,
 max:255 },
 **email**:{ 
type:String, 
required:true,
 max:255,
 min:6 },
 **password**:{
 type:String, 
required:true,
 max:1024, 
min:6 }, 
date:{ 
type:Date, 
default:Date.now }
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)
```

The final document is the Auth.js where I store data , here is the file

There is also a document with the schema of the data

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/User');
router.post('/register',async(req,res)=>{
const user = new User({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password
}); try{ const savedUser = await user.save(); res.send(savedUser); }catch(err){ res.status(400).send(err); } }); module.exports= router;
```

So far these are the codes I have. It works as expected and even in the console it outputs that it has connected to the database so no error in the connection. The path I am using to send post request is

**http://localhost:3000/api/user/register**

and the result i get is

```
{
"errors": { "name": { "properties": { "message": "Path name is required.", "type": "required", "path": "name" }, "kind": "required", "path": "name" }, "email": { "properties": { "message": "Path email is required.", "type": "required", "path": "email" }, "kind": "required", "path": "email" }, "password": { "properties": { "message": "Path password is required.", "type": "required", "path": "password" }, "kind": "required", "path": "password" } }, "_message": "User validation failed", "message": "User validation failed: name: Path name is required., email: Path email is required., password: Path password is required." }
```

I would like it to output so    {
"_id":"12345677763",
"name":"john doe",
"password":"apassword",
"date":"The date"
}mething like this

```
{
  "_id":"12345677763",
"name":"john doe",
"password":"apassword",
"date":"The date"
}
```

The code seems fine, but I cant pinpoint exactly how to solve the error, any help in looking at the code would be appreciated.

Comment: Might make sense to include the schema.

Comment: The userschema is in a file named User.js, i have it in the post and it is called userSchema

Comment: Doh, sorry, somehow missed it. Please consider formatting code so it's readable.

Comment: I have formatted it, hope it is understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you added body-parser middleware? If not add this line below

```
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express(); 
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 //Use below line
 app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```